# How to get the last three digit before a character in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying make a function `Makecode()`

The code has to look something like this

```
SV00000001-15
```

To create this I have to do like this.

```
function makeCode()
{
    $counter=000;
    $buf = 00000;
    $suf= $this->suf;
    $pre= $this-pref;

    $counter = addCount($this->lastCode);
    $code = $pref.$buf.$counter."-".$suf;

}
function addCount($code)
{

//I have to know how to get the last three digit before"-" and then return a number one greater than that .

}
```

In the above case `$this-lastCOde = 'SV00000001-15'`

**Some more explanation**

for the function addCount() input would be `SV00000001-15` and expected out put would be 002

I need out put as `002` ie I need to first get the last three digit before `"-"` and then increment it by one please note the returned value has to be in the three digit format

Please comment below if My question is not clear

Thanks & regards

So I have to

Comment: What is your `input` and what is your expected output?

Comment: for the function `addCount()` input would be ` SV00000001-15` and expected out put would be `002`.

Comment: use explode http://php.net/manual/ro/function.explode.php  $pieces = explode ("-", $code); $pieceYouWant = substr( $pieces[0], -3) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get last three characters from string like

```
substr("SV00000001-15", -3); // returns "-15"
```

OR

```
$no = substr(substr("SV00000001-15",0,strrpos("SV00000001-15","-")),-3); // returns "001"
echo sprintf('%03d', (int)$no + 1);  //returns 002
```

OR

```
$no = substr(explode("-","SV00000001-15")[0],-3); //returns 001
echo sprintf('%03d', (int)$no + 1);  //returns 002
```

In your function

```
function addCount($code)
{
   $no = substr(substr($code,0,strrpos($code,"-")),-3); // returns "001"
   echo sprintf('%03d', (int)$no + 1);  //returns 002
}
```

Comment: I need out put as `002` ie I need to first get the last three digit before `"-"` and then increment it by one please note the returned value has to be in the three digit format

Comment: He need to increment that 3-digit value nad need to be represented in 3-digit

Comment: @Sadikhasan Thanks a lot bro let me check , actually there could be simpler way also to get the last three digit using explode as explained by cassain in his comment above . I am just applying you code I will accept your answer soon thanks